# Show that $f(z) =x^3 + iy^3$ is differentiable at all points on the line $y=x$ and $y=-x$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Show that $f(z) =x^3 + iy^3$ is differentiable at all points on the line $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

So to do so, we must take $f_x$ and $f_y$ and have the property that $f_y =if_x$. But do we also need to explain where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous.

Or is there another way to go about this?

I appreciate any help.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

Take $u=x^3$ and $v=y^3$. So we have $u_x =3x^2$ and $v_y =3y^2$, as well as $u_y = v_x =0$. So by C-R we have $3x^2 = 3y^2$ solving for x or y, we get 2 solutions, y=x and y=-x, but is this the right approach to take?

Comment: Continuity of $f_x$ and $f_y$ is not part of the definition of differentiability. Enough to check the Cauchy-Riemann condition here.

Comment: gotcha I get that then thank you